# Convolution notation.

Tags: integration, notation, convolution

If $s(\cdot,\cdot),\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}(\cdot,\cdot) \in C(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R^{+}}), K(\cdot)\in C(\mathbb{R}) $ are integrable.
The convolution between $\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}(\cdot,t)$ and $K(\cdot)$ is:
 $$ (\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}*K)(x,t)=\int_\mathbb{R}{K(\xi)\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}(x-\xi,t)}d\xi . $$
 Assuming that the convolution commutes, then
 $$(K*\frac{\partial s}{\partial x})(x,t)=\int_\mathbb{R}{K(x-\xi)\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}(\xi,t)}d\xi .$$ or 
 $$ (K*\frac{\partial s}{\partial x})(x,t)=\int_\mathbb{R}{K(x-\xi)\frac{\partial s}{\partial \xi}(\xi,t)}d\xi.$$ ??

Comment: The first option is right. $s$ and $\partial s/\partial x$ are functions of the arguments $x,t$. For the convolution, you have to evaluate the latter at $(\xi,t)$. It would be better to use a different notation like $D_1s(x,t)$ for the partial derivative with respect to the first argument.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. Thank you so much